# subversive: only commit explicitly added files

Tags: eclipse, subversive

When I do a commit from subversive it populates a list of (and selects by default) any new files in my project directory.  I want only those files which I have **explicitly** added to version control to show up in the commit dialog.

This seems to be the same basic question as this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638834/subversion-stage-files-to-commit-explicitly) question, but I really want to involve git.

This is a huge pain because people keep accidentally checking in random generated files and directories (e.g. VC++ temp files: **/Release/vc70.pdb, buildLog.html ) and random settings files for eclipse plugins.

- I found a `"Check the new resources in the commit dialog"` option under `Preferences > Team > SVN`.  This just prevents them from being auto selected, but I want them not to show up at all.
- I also tried isolating all the different change sets available under 'Models'.  Even with **No** change sets selected commit still adds all uncommitted files on the file system to the commit list.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse lets you specify resource name patterns so that files which match a pattern are excluded from version control.  Find it at Window..Preferences/Team/Ignored Resources.  You can specify paths like */temp/something.*, or just filename patterns like *.tmp.

I'm using Perforce, not svn, but I think it works the same way with any version control plugin.

[image]

Comment: I saw the exclude patterns, and it works for some things.  I can't exclude *.html since my web project has html files but visual studio generates buildLog.html files.  Adding tmp/something is essentially the same as finding all the generated file directories and adding those to svn:ignore which we do whenever we find them.